# Junit for a method having new call to create an object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write JUnit for the following method inside `MyClass1`:

```
public static String myFirstMethod(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
        String result = null;
        Something something = MyUtility.getSomething();
        if (something != null) {
            OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
            try {
                result = otherClass.mySecondMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.unexpected();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My test class is something like this:

```
private OtherClass otherClass;
private RequiredClass1 requiredClass1;
private RequiredClass2 requiredClass2;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    requiredClass1 = mock(RequiredClass1.class);
    requiredClass2 = mock(RequiredClass2.class);
    otherClass = new OtherClass(new RequiredClass3(), requiredClass1, new RequiredClass4(), requiredClass2);
    when(requiredClass1.getSomething(any(SomeClass.class), eq("abc"))).thenReturn("abc");
    when(requiredClass1.getSomething(any(SomeClass.class), eq("pqr"))).thenReturn("pqr");
    when(requiredClass2.getSomeBoolean(any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);
}

@Test
public void generateLinkSmartUrlTest() throws Exception {
   /* Something something = mock(Something.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyUtility.class);
    when(MyUtility.getSomething()).thenReturn(something);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(OtherClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(this.otherClass); */
    String arg1 = "abc";
    String expectedResult1 = "abc";
    String expectedResult2 = "abc";
    /*assertEquals(expectedResult1, MyClass1.myFirstMethod(arg1, "", ""));*/
    assertEquals(expectedResult1, this.otherClass.mySecondMethod(arg1, "", ""));
}
```

The unit test runs as above when I am calling `this.otherClass.mySecondMethod` directly.

However, if I uncomment the commented part so that I can test `this.otherClass.mySecondMethod`, I get `nullPointerException` somewhere inside `otherClass` call stack.

How can I make PowerMockito to consider everything inside `before` method when I am doing this:

```
 PowerMockito.whenNew(OtherClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(this.otherClass);
```

In other words, `before` method sets several properties inside `otherClass` object, but the `otherClass` object returned by `whenNew` call above has all properties as `null`. How can I get `PowerMockito` to return `otherClass` with all its properties set on the `new OtherClass()` call inside `myFirstMethod`.

Comment: you can use spy.
Ref: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation

Comment: so why not mock `OtherClass` as well? something in the instance is causing a problem.